# Alert before installing Firefox addon-sdk in a lower version browser

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to stop/alert a user when he/she tries to install firefox addon-sdk in an old version browser ?

Comment: This isn;t a complete answer, but you can get the version of Firefox being run using the xul-app module https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_xul-app

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentRunningVersionCompareTo30 = Services.vc.compare(Services.appinfo.version, 30);
if (currentRunningVersionCompareTo30 < 0) {
  Services.prompt.alert(null, 'Version Compare Result', 'You are running Firefox ' + Services.appinfo.version + ' and this add-on was designed for optimal performance in at least Firefox 30');
} else if (currentRunningVersionCompareTo30 == 0) {
  Services.prompt.alert(null, 'Version Compare Result', 'You are running Firefox 30, I designed this add-on for FF30 kewl!');
} else if (currentRunningVersionCompareTo30 > 0) {
  Services.prompt.alert(null, 'Version Compare Result', 'You are running Firefox ' + Services.appinfo.version + ' you are way ahead of me! I made this add-on using Firefox 30...');
}
```

or use the functions @canuckistani linked in his comment there